# why do I need to make sumproduct an array formula to make it work

Tags: excel-formula

lets keep this example simple.  I am trying to figure out why the count is coming up correct when I enter the formula as a CSE but wrong when I don't when the whole formula is just sumproduct.

Example 1

```
    B      |       C      |        D         |         E        |       F
condtion 1 |  condition 2 | strings Jan 2016 | strings Feb 2016 | strings Mar 2016
15/06/01   |  17/06/01    |       2          |         4        |       6
```

Example 2

```
condtion 1 |  condition 2 | strings Jan 2016 | strings  ONLY   | strings Mar 2016
15/06/01   |  17/06/01    |      2           |        4        |      6
```

I was tinkering with a formula to add up the values if their date in the first row was roughly between the dates in condition 1 and condition 2 which are excel date serials.  I came up with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((DATE(RIGHT($D$1:$F$1,4),MONTH(MID($D$1:$F$1,9,3)&"-1"),1)>=$B2)*(DATE(RIGHT($D$1:$F$1,4),MONTH(MID($D$1:$F$1,9,3)&"-1"),1)<$C2)*(LEFT($D$1:$F$1,7)="strings")*$D$2:$F$2)
```

And it works fine for Example 1.  For Example 2 when I make it so the date is not in the string, the formula produces #Value.  So I start breaking the formula down into parts and have it just count the months >= condition 1 and wrap things in IFERROR(...,0) as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(--(DATE(RIGHT($D$1:$F$1,4),MONTH(MID($D$1:$F$1,9,3)&"-1"),1)>=$B2),0))
```

When I enter it normally I get 0 for both examples, but if I enter it as a CSE I get 3 for example 1 and 2 for example 2, which are the anticipated answer.

It was my understanding that sumproduct created array like calculations within its brackets.  Why do I need to enter the above formula as a CSE when it should already be performing that way?

Is there a way to use sumproduct without making it an array in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the IF() Function or IFERROR() or any IFx() Function inside a SUMPRODUCT() you need to use CSE.

Comment: If you use the IFERROR() out side the SUMPRODUCT() you won't need to use de CSE.
`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(DATE(RIGHT($D$1:$F$1,4),MONTH(MID($D$1:$F$1,9,3)&"-1"),1)>=$B2)),0)`